# Best way to use jQuery and ajax to attempt to write to locked record?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, multithreading

We have a desktop and a web application, which share some database records. I am currently trying to save information into our user record (which both applications currently share), and when it is open in the desktop application the user record is locked.

Right now, the web application simply throws an error if the user record is locked when trying to make edits/update information.

I have been tasked with updating the user record with certain information as soon as the user record becomes unlocked (we are more concerned with it being locked for only a few minutes at a time, rather than hours)

One of the things I have to save to the user object is the menu positions of a javascript built sortable menu...so I'm wanting a jQuery ajax call that works in the background and attempts to save the menu item positions until the user record is unlocked.

I have a generic handler (.ashx) set up that calls the update methods in the user object in order to save the menu positions and other data. I know how to make ajax calls and all that, I just can't wrap my head around how to have a background process that continually tries to save until the record is unlocked.

Maybe a worker function similar to:

```
(function worker() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/test.html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                setTimeout(worker, 5000);
            }
        });
    })();
```

...which has a timeout, or a setInterval?  I admittedly don't have any code written for this (other than the methods in the back end which does a check for the locked record, and attempts to save to the user object).

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

```
  try
  {        
    UniFile userSecurityFile = CurrentSession.CreateUniFile("USER.SECURITY");
    userSecurityFile.WriteField(this.UserId, 443);        
  }
  catch (UniFileException ex)
  {
    Exception betterExceptionToThrow = null;
    if (ex.IsRecordLockedError())
    {
      betterExceptionToThrow = new RecordAccessException(RecordAccessIssueType.Locked, "Could not save because record is locked");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't even attempt to solve this using Javascript - JS is good to get data from the server or to post data to it but you have no way to know if the same user is using another browser at the same time or another machine - these may all generate the same write request to the server at the same time.

You need to have thread-safe server-side entrypoints that perform CRUD operations on your data. You *can* call these entry points using JS / Ajax but these functions will have to catch exceptions from the underlying database layer and return some kind of error code (or other error status) to the browser that tells the UI layer that the write attempt failed. There's no way to guarantee that the save will work without errors and the client may have to retry several times to succeed.

As the server-side code attempts to complete the write operation, you'll have to make sure you deal with concurrency problems in the data layer of your application. For more information, read [Concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) - this, however, is a huge topic and a simplified article won't get you far. You'll have to decide if you can allow multiple write attempts (last one wins) or if all write attempts on a changed record should fail.

**Edit:**

If I misunderstood your question and your server-side code already handles all of the above then in the browser all you need to do is set up an Ajax call, wait for the return value and if it failed, try again for *N* number of times. In this case, your sample code is roughly what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I edited my original post to show one of the methods, and how I am catching a record locked error so there are no concurrency issues.  I just wanted to continuously make an ajax call, until the record is not locked and successfully saves (or if using ajax and a worker function was the best route to take!)

Comment: @vinco83 Your idea would probably work fine in the client - if one call fails, you can retry so many times until the call succeeds.

Comment: @vinco83 You may want to move your `UniverseRecord.UnlockRecord("USER.SECURITY", this.UserId);` call to a `finally` block to make sure your record gets unlocked even if there's an exception after the record has been locked.

Comment: Thank you! I will mark this answer as accepted and carry on with the worker function idea. Also, thanks for the tip on moving that to the finally block. Much appreciated!